# Is there a LibreOffice Calc video tutorial available?

Tags: libreoffice

Hello I am new to Ubuntu and was wondering if anyone could hook me up with a crash-course style video tutorial (preferably in English) running through the LibreOffice Calc application.  While I understand this is similar to Microsoft Excel, I do not have much experience with that program either.  I am trying to learn the Calc program basics quickly for a new job.  It would also be helpful to gain some knowledge regarding the compatibility issues between the two programs.  Text links with "How-To" instructions are welcomed as well,however a video tutorial is ideal.  Thanks!

Comment: check links http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/ and https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Welcome_to_the_Calc_Help and https://help.libreoffice.org/

Comment: To the close voters: I don't see how this is "not about Ubuntu". LibreOffice is part of the software stack Ubuntu ships with by default and there are thousands of questions concerning LO an AskUbuntu. You might argue that ask.libreoffice.org would be a slightly more fitting place to ask - and I wouldn't disagree -, but that site is not part of the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 5):

*Spreadsheet Tutorial - Libre Office, Calc* by TheFrugalComputerGuy:

[image]